# $_data vs $this->_data - PHP

Tags: php, class, this

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `$_data vs $this->_data`

```
class ProductModel
{

    var $_data = null; <--- defined here

    function test() 
    {
       $this->_data = <--- but it's accessed using $this
    }

}
```

I know in PHP `var` is used to define class properties but Why is it accessed using `$this`. Shouldn't it be like `$this->$_data` ? What's OOP concept is being used here ? Is it a PHP specific?

Comment: `$this->$_data` $_data treat as local variable and it gives value of variable so $this->value of variable

Comment: The usage of `var $_data` has been superseded by the visibility modifiers such as `public`, `private` and `protected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP along with several other popular programming languages such as Java (it's important to note that PHP's Object Oriented choices were at least partially inspired by Java) refer to the current object instance in context as `this`.  You can think of `this`, (or `$this in PHP`) as the "current object instance."

Inside of class methods, `$this` refers to the current object instance.

A very small example using what you have above:

```
$_data = 'some other thing';
public function test() {
   $_data = 'something';
   echo $_data;
   echo $this->_data;
}
```

The above will output `somethingsome other thing`.  Class members are stored along with the object instance, but local variables are only defined within the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't. Since PHP can evaluate member names dynamically, the line

```
$this->$_data
```

refers to a class member, which name is specified in local `$data` variable. Consider this:

```
class ProductModel
{

    var $_data = null; <--- defined here

    function test() 
    {
       $member = '_data';
       $this->$member = <--- here you access $this->_data, not $this->member
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var $_data` defines a class variable, `$this->_data` accesses it.

If you do `$this->$foo` it means something else, just like `$$foo` : if you set `$foo = 'bar'`, those two expressions are respectively evaluated as `$this->bar` and `$bar`